# How to open the webpage in a separate full screen window on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open the webpage in a full screen window (As most of the banking sites do) on page load. I am able to do it on clicking a link but when I keep it in onload function it is going into infinite loop.

Following is what I have done

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a class="sprite_stumbleupon" href="#"  onclick="return windowpop()">Link</a>
</li>
</ul>

<script>
 function windowpop() {
 var leftPosition, topPosition;
 //Allow for borders.
 leftPosition =  10;
 //Allow for title and status bars.
 topPosition = 50;

 //Open the window.
 window.open(window.location.href, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + 
 screen.height + ",width=" + screen.width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + 
 leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",
 screenY=" +    topPosition +",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
 }

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The above code is working fine when I click the url. What I want is to perform the same functionality while loading the page, so I have called windowpop() function in onload inside body tag. Then it is keep on loading the new window. No clue on how to load new window only once. Any help is highly appriciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can not go to fullscreen mode without an interaction from user! #browsers security policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're declaring the name of the resized window as `Window2`. Maybe you could just use it to your advantage and add an if statement:

```
if(window.name != 'Window2'){
    window.open(...);
}else{
    alert("This is fullscreen!");
}
```

That should open the window in full screen mode only once.